# codeigniter how to update a single attribute in a tuple

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to update a single column (tuple) within attribute in table.  i have the array shown below in controller.

```
$promotion_info = array(     
    'category'      => $this->input->post('category'),
    'rank'          => $this->input->post('rank'),
    'date_of_start' => $date_of_promotion 
);
```

i passed it to model as shown below:-

```
$this->insert_model->form_promotion($fno, $promotion_info);
```

on model i want to update column with date_of_promotion. Then inserting a new row (attribute) with the value contained in array.

how can i update that column with the single value in array

Answer (score 0):

Following [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data):

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable'); // gives UPDATE mytable SET field = field+1 WHERE id = 2

$this->db->set('field', 'field+1');
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable'); // gives UPDATE `mytable` SET `field` = 'field+1' WHERE `id` = 2
```

*In your case it could be something like:*

```
$array = array(
    'category' => $name,
    'rank' => $title,
    'date_of_start' => $status
);
$this->insert_model->form_promotion($fno, $data);
```

In model:

```
$this->db->set($data);// this is case if you need to update all 3 values
//if you need to update only one value from the array than
//$this->db->set('date_of_start', $data['date_of_start']);

$this->db->where('date_of_start', "SOME_EXISTING_DATE_FROM_TABLE");
$this->db->insert('mytable');//
```